# How to show several fields values in one textField

Tags: jasper-reports

Can nay one help to add multiple DB field values in one field.

Say i have 3 DB fields:

```
Name
Address
Age
```

I want to display all 3 fields in the same field:

```
John Peter 28.
```

I tried doing 3 fields next to each other and it did work but when i wrap text. It looks really bad:

**Name**

```
Jo.pe.28
hn te
   r
```

My requirement is show data in one text field, for example: **John.Peter.26**

Answer (score 21):

If you want to put them in one line (which i guess is the case), its straight forward.

Put this as a text box `$F{Name} + "." + $F{Address} + "." + $F{Age}.toString()`

Or you can use string concatenation (I dont personally like the syntax, take more effort to understand) `$F{Name}.concat(".").concat($F{Address}).concat(".").concat($F{Age})`

Comment: There's also `msg("{0}.{1}.{2}", $F{name}, $F{Address}, $F{Age})`.

Answer (score 7):

## The SQL Method

Why not concatenate all the 3 fields you need in the query you use itself like (Assuming you are with `Postgres`.),

```
select (name || address|| to_char(age)) as data from my_table
```

## In Ireport

As suggested,

```
$F{Name} + "." + $F{Address} + "." + $F{Age}.toString()
```

too works if needed to make it work from the report.

Make sure that all your fields are of same data type.

Comment: Plus user might need/want to use the fields separately in other places.